# What is the dimension of $U\cap W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U.W \subset V$ be two subspaces different from $V$, a vector space whose dimension is $n$, if the dimensions of both $U$ and $W$ are equal to $n-1$ then, what is the dimension of $U \cap W$?

Intuitively, I know that $\dim(U \cap W)\leq n-1$. I thought that perhaps Grassman's formula ($\dim(U)+\dim(W)=\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W)$) could help me solve this problem, but then I realized that I would need more information about $\dim(U+W)$ which I only intuitively know to be less or equal to $n$.

Edit:
I think I have an idea, using Grassman's formula: dim(U+W)=dim(U)+dim(W)−dim(U∩W)
. Because dim(W)=dim(U)=n−1 and dim(V)=n then n−1≤dim(U+W)≤n. Therefore n−1≤dim(U)+dim(W)−dim(U∩W)≤n ⇒ n−1≤(n−1)+(n−1)−dim(U∩W)≤n ⇒ −n+1≤−dim(U∩W)≤−n+2 ⇒ n−2≤dim(U∩W)≤n−1 Is there a way to decide if dim(U∩W)=n−2 or dim(U∩W)=n−1 or is the inequality the best possible answer?

Comment: Treat the cases $U\subset W$ and $U\nsubseteq W$ separately. Determine $\dim(U+W)$ in each case and use your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $U\ne W$, otherwise the answer is obvious.

Neither can be contained in the other, because they have the same dimension. Thus there is a vector in $W$ not in $U$ and so $U+W=V$.

Now Grassmann's formula tells us that
$$
\dim(U\cap W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U+W)=n-1+n-1-n=n-2
$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ through the origin in $\mathbb R^2$. If they are different lines, then the intersection is 0-dimensional. But if they are the same line, then the intersection is 1-dimensional. So, without more information about $U$ and $W$, we can only get a range of values for $\dim(U \cap W)$.

Comment: $U$ and $W$ are codimension 1. So the range is pretty narrow.

Comment: I think I have an idea, using Grassman's formula: $dim(U+W)=dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U\cap W)$.

Because $dim(W)=dim(U)=n-1$ and $dim(V)=n$ then $n-1 \leq dim(U+W) \leq n$.

Therefore $n-1 \leq dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U\cap W) \leq n$ $\Rightarrow$ $n-1 \leq(n-1)+(n-1)-dim(U\cap W) \leq n$ 

$\Rightarrow$ $-n+1 \leq-dim(U\cap W) \leq -n+2$ $\Rightarrow$ $n-2 \leq dim(U\cap W) \leq n-1$

Is there a way to decide if $dim(U\cap W)=n-2$ or $dim(U \cap W)=n-1$ or is the inequality the best possible answer?

Comment: Nice deductions -- I'd incorporate them into your question as opposed to in these comments

Comment: As to your final question, there is a way to decide. As @DanielKruse is hinting at, split into cases where $U = W$ and $U \neq W$. This will tell you when the intersection is codimension 1 or codimension 2.

Comment: Oh thanks! I finally understand how to proceed.